# On running the dotnet --version or dotnet run command on Visual Studio or VSCode Poweshell, we are getting the Windows popup asking for App selection

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022, powershell-7.0

On running the dotnet --version or dotnet run command on Visual Studio or VSCode PowerShell, we are getting the Windows popup asking for App selection. Same issue doesn't occur on command prompt when same commands are run. Why this could be?

Have already:

1. Verified the Environment variables for dotnet, they look fine.
2. Have already installed the latest version of Poweshell v7

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvUhr.png)

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, It seems that you are opening a file the system does not know how to handle. So the popup is asking you to specify the file extension's application it is used with.

This does not occur when executing `dotnet --version` and if I had to guess based off the screenshot provided, combined with the information available, you may be attempting to open `UserController.cs` at the same time as when you are running the version check.

Hope that helps.